# Apply dynamic where condition in the database view (oracle - 12c, mysql 5+)

Tags: mysql, oracle, view

Can I create a view with dynamic "WHERE" clause. This where clause will be built based on user and certain conditions

This is my ***transaction table***:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| Job ID | Customer | Department |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 1      | ABC      | Tanker     |
| 2      | ABC      | Dry        |
| 3      | MEX      | Tanker     |
| 4      | MEX      | Dry        |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

- User A - require to see all transaction
- User B - require to see all Transactions of Tanker department
- User C - require to see all transactions of Tanker department but belongs to customer ABC

My user wise setup has header details

***Access key*** - this is binary code for each segment I used to filter data (first position is department, second is customer and 0 mean all and 1 mean select/limited access)

**Header:**

```
+------+------------+
| User | Access key |
+------+------------+
| A    | 00         |
| B    | 10         |
| C    | 11         |
+------+------------+
```

**Detail table:**

```
+------+------------+--------+
| User |   Segment  | Value  |
+------+------------+--------+
| B    | Department | Tanker |
| C    | Department | Tanker |
| C    | Customer   | ABC    |
+------+------------+--------+
```

Now I need to filter the data based on above user wise setup. Instead of fixing the where clause in the view to fetch the data, can I build the where clause dynamically based on the user and then pass and execute with the select query?
Please help, I have 2 dbs (MySQL and Oracle)

Even alternative suggestions to archive this requirement also most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle this sounds like a use case for Virtual Private Database: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm

or for a pipeline function: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.

Personally I would recommend VPD if at all possible. It is the more secure solution.